# no wired connection and wirewireless disabled

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, broadcom

I am new to Linux kubuntu 14, i tried installing kubuntu 14.04 without internet connection which went smoothly, when i finish installing i was surprise to get a network or connection icon with a red sign showing wireless disable.

Since i have been battling with all kind of solution to fix this problem i can't just find any, i went to internet point and also try to connect ethernet wire it didn't work also can someone help me. when i run

```
lspci -nn
```

I get

```
02.06.1 Firewire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Texas instruments PCIxx12 OHCI compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller [104c:803a]
02.0e.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c](rev 02)
10.00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then:

```
sudo modprobe -v ssb
sudo modprobe -v b44
```

your ehternet should come on, give it a minute then do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot

Comment: i tried the sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source, it said unable to locate package bcmwl-kernel-source